# Python insert images in docx one by one

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, arraylist

I have one folder with docx documents and other folder with png images. My program should take the first image and insert into the first document, then it should take the second image and insert into the second document etc.

```
os.chdir(r"C:\Users\krupn\OneDrive\Работа\ДЛЯ РПН\CreateWord\Result")
filenames = []
filenames.extend(os.listdir("."))
os.chdir (r"C:\Users\krupn\OneDrive\Documents\Pictures\Screenshots")
pictures = glob.glob(r"C:\Users\krupn\OneDrive\Documents\Pictures\Screenshots\*.png")


os.chdir(r"C:\Users\krupn\OneDrive\Работа\ДЛЯ РПН\CreateWord\Result")
for file in filenames:
document = Document (file)
for x in range (0, len(pictures)):
    document.add_picture(pictures[x], width=Inches(10))
document.save (file)
```

I wrote a code, but it insert ALL images into each docx document. Do you have any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `zip` function to iterate over two lists at the same time:

```
os.chdir(r"C:\Users\krupn\OneDrive\Работа\ДЛЯ РПН\CreateWord\Result")
for picture, file in zip(pictures, filenames):
    document = Document(file)
    document.add_picture(picture, width=Inches(10))
    document.save(file)
```

Also make sure that number of images and files in the lists are the same.